# Android: static reference / non-static method when using findViewById(ID)

Tags: java, android, findviewbyid, static

Let me start by confessing that I come from an Erlang background and am new to Android and Java programming... to be honest object orientation is giving me a headache. :)

I am having some trouble with the sticky old chestnut: "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method".
Basically I am writing an app that receives XML from our server and uses it to create a form to be filled in by the user.
I have managed to successfully parse the XML and create (and display) the form. I assign each EditText field it's own ID using a (very) simple algorithm that I can recreate later.

I am busy with the submit button, which makes a HTTP post back to our server with the user entered details.
My problem comes in when I try to retrieve the values that the user has entered into the form.
What I am attempting to do is loop through my IDs, open each EditText instance using  EditText.findViewById(ID) and retrieve its text using getText().
When i do so however I receive the error "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method".

Now I've done some reading and the way I understand it is that this is because I am trying access a a non-static method in a static way and in order to make it static I need to call the method of an instance rather than the class in general... the problem is that I am calling it IN ORDER to get that particular instance and I can't figure out what I should be doing differently.

I would really appreciate any help, advice or further reading that anyone has for me.

Cheers,
Bevan

p.s. Here are the relevant sections of my code

```
private static LinearLayout renderForm(...) 
{
    //Build Fields
    ...
    //Build Buttons
    ...
    Button BT = new Button(App);
    BT.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            ...
            for(int j = 0; j < FFListLength;  j++)
            {
                EditText BinField = (EditText) EditText.findViewById(20000+j);
                ...
            }
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Update:
After reading JB Nizet's answer I realized what I was doing wrong.
I have changed the line:
    EditText BinField = (EditText) EditText.findViewById(20000+j);
to:
    EditText binField = (EditText) lContent.findViewById(20000+j);

where lContent is the content of my view.

Thanks for the assistance.
Bevan

Comment: Please respect Java naming conventions: variables start with a lower-case letter. If you respect these conventions, you'll be able to distinguish calls to static methods from calls to instance methods easier.

Comment: Thanks for the advice JB Nizet, I'll try to stick to that. In Erlang it is precisely the opposite, variables start with capitals while functions start with lowercase... yet another change for me to get used to.

Comment: variable and functions start with lowercase in java . classes and enums start with uppercase . also ,note that your "findViewById" call is not recommended because of its large loop. consider saving an array/list of items that you know of, of the views you wish to handle. if you wish , you can have the ids have the name "edittext1", "edittext2",... , and use getidentifier to get their id , and then go over them in a loop , and stop when you don't get their id .

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to comment on the Android specific problems. Only on the general compilation error you're getting. Let's take an example:

```
public class User {
    private String name;

    public User(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

To be able to call the getName() method, you need an instance of User:

```
User john = new User("John");
String johnsName = john.getName();
```

What you're doing is calling the getName() method without any instance of User:

```
String someName = User.getName();
```

This doesn't make sense. You don't have any user. Only the User class.

As noted in my comment; variables should start with a lower-case letter. Classes start with an upper-case letter. If you respect this convention, everything is clearer:

```
john.getName(); // instance method call on object john, of type User.
User.getName(); // static method call on User class.
```

Comment: Thanks, that does make sense. Now, my problem is that I need to open the User with name == "John". Is there a way of doing that?